# Win32 QueueUserAPC API alternative in .NET

Tags: .net, api, winapi, asynchronous, synchronization

What would be the closest .NET alternative for [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Should I use [SynchronizationContext.Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) for that?

Comment: QUA works at a much lower level.  But sure, same idea.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  An APC effective "takes over" a thread in an alterable state--diverting it (temporarily) from other potentially pending work.  There's nothing in .NET that specifically does that.

Comment: @Peter, in this context I'm just trying to get a better picture on API mapping between Win32 and .NET. Previously I used QueueUserAPC for scheduling some profiling tasks.

Comment: I wouldn't say that QueueUserAPC really maps to anything in .NET.  If you're just looking to run code asynchronously, I would recommend using `Task` and Task<T>` and/or `async`/`await`.

Comment: I believe Monitor does alertable waits so you could continue to use QUA. That said it seems like a bad architecture to hijack threads at kind of random points to do something else. I never understood what QUA is good for. Always seems to be a bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

Modern .NET tries to abstract away raw threading, and to replace with higher level libraries such as Task Parallel Library (TPL) or Reactive Extensions.

I am not sure that in .NET there is an "alertable" state for a thread, like you can obtain with `SleepEx`, but you can always use TPL to queue a work item on the process thread pool.

```
Task.Start( () => { /* do work * });
```

This works particularly well if you're doing some sort of asynchronous IO operation in there, which will allow the same thread to be reused for running another queued task, while your original task is doing an asynchronous operation.